# "The operation could not be completed" alert on iPhone Phonegap

Tags: iphone, cordova, html5-audio

I am creating a iPhone app using Phonegap (cordova 1.7). Part of the functionality involves playing remotely hosted mp3 files. Everything works just fine, except sometimes (very rarely) an alert comes up saying `The operation could not be completed`. It may be worth noting that I use HTML5 audio to play the mp3s; also, I have whitelisted all possible URLs in the `info.plist` file, so that shouldn't be an issue either.

Just wondering if there's any way to prevent the alerts from appearing.